# Unitialized constant when using custom exceptions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to create a custom exceptions for my app. I have a sample library in my libs folder with the following folder structure:

```
- lib/
|
|--social/
  |
  |-- bandcamp.rb
```

And this `bandcamp.rb` file contents looks following:

```
module Social
  class ExampleException < Exception; end

  class Bandcamp
    def some_method()
    end
  end
end
```

And the thing is, i can use a `Social::Bandcamp.new.some_method` anywhere in my app and it works just fine but i can't access `Social::ExampleException` nor raise it anywhere. It gives me

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Social::ExampleException
```

Have you any idea what am i possibly doing wrong? I'm quite new to creating own libs so i'm sure i've misunderstood something.

Comment: I guess you mean `Social::Bandcamp.new.some_method`?

Comment: yes, exactly, sorry for this ;) Fixed.

Comment: That's weird. Did you try `raise ::Social::ExampleException`?

Comment: yep. It's not working neither

Comment: Are you monkey patching something there?

Comment: Well, actually i've just done that simple lib (100% of my own code) with two or three methods inside and now i'm trying to use it in my app. Nothing complex ;) It's available on github actually. Code is probably a huge mess but maybe it'll be helpfull: https://github.com/mbajur/khcpl/tree/feature/lib_organize . It's even simpler. The exceptions are available in `lib/khcpl.rb` and i can't use `Khcpl::NoUrlGiven` for example.

Comment: @mbajur are you referring to this file https://github.com/mbajur/khcpl/blob/3db78a7c7b575fca6f39b6392c737c0b941e6c24/lib/khcpl/player/bandcamp.rb, if no which of the files is the exception not working as expected???

Comment: @bjhaid: Source in this branch is half-done so there are a lot of useless trash files but let's say the good one is: `lib/khcpl.rb`. If i'll try to run `Khcpl::NoUrlGiven` in `rails console`, i'm getting Unitialized constant error.

Comment: Have you required your library?

Comment: Yep. Using `config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)` line in `application.rb`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that `lib/` files are autoloaded (`config.autoload_paths`).
Autoload depends on filenames in order to find needed class.
The file named `bandcamp.rb` will be loaded only when you call `Social::Bandcamp` and only then you'll be able to access other classes defined there.

The solution is to create separate files for exceptions or turn on eager loading of this directory.

Comment: yeah, sounds reasonable. Thank you for explanation. But still, in the repo posted in question comments, i have a `lib/khcpl.rb` file with custom exceptions and they are not available to me for some reason (and i have added a `eager_load_paths` to my config file). Error raised is the same, Uninitialized constant.

Comment: I can't see this file in your repo. This may be somehow related to the fact that your App is namespaced in `Khcpl` module. Check out more eager loading options here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html

Comment: Yes, i've changed my exceptions class name to something different than my app name and now it's working, thank you for your time Bartosz!

Answer (score 4):

You are probably being bitten by Rails classes' eager loading. Why? See:

```
2.0.0p353 :001 > Social.constants
 => [] 
2.0.0p353 :002 > raise Social::ExampleException
NameError: uninitialized constant Social::ExampleException
2.0.0p353 :003 > Social::Bandcamp
 => Social::Bandcamp 
2.0.0p353 :004 > Social.constants
 => [:ExampleException, :Bandcamp] 
2.0.0p353 :005 > raise Social::ExampleException
Social::ExampleException: Social::ExampleException
```

TIf you want to change that behaviour you should turn on eager loading of `lib` directory (by default only `app` is loaded), to do this add to your `environment.rb` (or specific environment setting):

```
  config.eager_load_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```